# plotting timestamp speed profile from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, seaborn

My dataframe is a time series of car trips and corresponding speed at relatively high granular.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'session_id': [69,69,69,69,69,69,69,71,71,71,71,71,86,86,86,86,86,86],
 'timestamp': ['2016-04-01 08:04:00','2016-04-01 08:04:05','2016-04-01 08:04:10',
               '2016-04-01 08:04:15','2016-04-01 08:04:22','2016-04-01 08:04:30',
               '2016-04-01 08:04:37','2016-04-01 01:04:10','2016-04-01 01:04:13',
               '2016-04-01 01:04:20','2016-04-01 01:04:24','2016-04-01 01:04:31',
               '2016-04-01 17:56:46','2016-04-01 17:58:54','2016-04-01 18:04:00',
               '2016-04-01 18:04:50','2016-04-01 18:05:21','2016-04-01 18:06:10'],
 'speed': [0.0,26.8551,27.673,18.0626,21.4778,17.6581,24.4941,14.42,8.94,13.69,
           0.0,0.37,16.5,0.0,17.25,3.5,11.75,6.25]
 })

df.head()
  session_id    timestamp         speed
0   69      2016-04-01 08:04:00   0.0000
1   69      2016-04-01 08:04:05  26.8551
2   69      2016-04-01 08:04:10  27.6730
3   69      2016-04-01 08:04:15  18.0626
4   69      2016-04-01 08:04:22  21.4778
```

Data was was recorded at different time of the day, for 5 days.

I need a way to plot the speed profile as a lineplot. For example speed on y-axis, time on x-axis. Because the sessions were recorded for long period, I am interested in plotting trip from begin to end. Instead, I would be interested in the starting speed, something like 15-minutes beginning.

Since data was recorded on different date in some case, I removed the data part, and wanted to plot the time part instead.

```py
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].dt.time
df.head()
    session_id  timestamp   speed
0      69       08:04:00    0.0000
1      69       08:04:05    26.8551
2      69       08:04:10    27.6730
3      69       08:04:15    18.0626
4      69       08:04:22    21.4778
```

Attempt to plot data:

```py
sns.lineplot(data=df, x='timestamp', y='speed')

TypeError: Invalid object type at position 0
```

- Is there a way to plot the speed of profile of each session against time?
- Can I reset the times, in a way that they both starts at same time, say `00.00`, so I can easily compare the trend in speed?

**EDIT**

Following the answer by @abokey, I can now plot this like so:

```py
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
sns.lineplot(data=df, x='timestamp', y='speed', hue='session_id')
```

Which gives:

[image]

Is there a way to reset all sessions' start time so that the their plots start at same time, like say `00:00`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your timestamp to a string by using [**`pandas.Series.dt.strftime`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) before calling [**`seaborn.lineplot`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html).

Try this :

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

sns.lineplot(data=df, x='timestamp', y='speed')
```

##### # Output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Converting timestamps to strings is a terrible idea.  Seaborn will treat them as categorical and their relative distances between each other are ignored.  This is why the points in your plot are all evenly spaced on the x-axis.

Try plotting `sns.lineplot(x=["1", "9", "10"], y=[1,4,2])` for example.

Here is a solution to your last question *"Is there a way to reset all sessions' start time so that the their plots start at same time"*

Convert `timestamp` column from string to `pandas.Timestamp`

```
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"])
```

Group on `session_id` and create column called `timedelta` of `pandas.Timedelta` for the difference between the timestamps and the minimum timestamp

```
def make_relative_timedelta(d):
    origin = d["timestamp"].min()
    return d.assign(timedelta = d["timestamp"] - origin)

df = df.groupby("session_id").apply(make_relative_timedelta)
```

plot

```
sns.lineplot(data=df, x='timedelta', y='speed', hue='session_id')
```

[image]

If you wanted to convert the timedelta column to something like number of minutes, rather than use timedelta directly (which will plot in nanoseconds) then do this to convert to float:

```
df["timedelta"] = ["timedelta"]/pd.Timedelta("1m")
```